# Preview Bootstrap 3 Grid Layout as Phone and Tablet without resizing the browser window?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is there a way to preview the Bootstrap Grid (Tablet View and Phone View) without resizing the browser window? 
I would like to provide preview buttons (preview as Tablet) and (preview as Phone).

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I would like to do the same thing ( have a preview button for tablet/PC/phone )

Comment: No Dave. I left it aside for a while since I was busy with other projects. If you find a solution, please let me know :)

Comment: What I ended up doing was opening a new window with ```window.open``` passing the size information and calling ```window.resizeTo``` along with ```window.focus``` if window.open was already called and the window hasn't been closed. Not exactly what I wanted but it works.

Comment: another way is to place the website in an iFrame and resize that iFrame as needed. But it's not what I wanted too..

Comment: Dave, please see my answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to think of a working solution using simple css

```
.media-320, .media-480, .media-600, .media-800, .media-768, .media-1024 { background: #666; }
.media-320 body, .media-480 body, .media-600 body, .media-800 body, .media-768 body, .media-1024 body {margin: auto;background: white;position: relative;overflow: hidden; top:50px}

.media-320 body { width: 320px; height: 480px}
.media-320 .main-wrapper, .media-320 .container {width:320px}

.media-480 body { width: 480px; height: 320px}
.media-480 .main-wrapper, .media-480 .container {width:480px}

.media-600 body { width: 600px; height: 800px}
.media-600 .main-wrapper, .media-600 .container {width:600px}

.media-800 body { width: 800px; height: 600px}
.media-800 .main-wrapper, .media-800 .container {width:800px}

.media-768 body { width: 768px; height: 1024px}
.media-768 .main-wrapper, .media-768 .container {width:768px}

.media-1024 body { width: 1024px; height: 768px}
.media-1024 .main-wrapper, .media-1024 .container {width:1024px}

.media-320 div[class^="col-sm-"] , .media-480 div[class^="col-sm-"], .media-600 div[class^="col-sm-"] { float: none;margin-left: 0;margin-right: 0; width:100%}
```

Then edit your html tag manually or dynamically to be

```
<html class="media-320">
```

or

```
<html class="media-600">
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

Get the script from this page and drag it into your bookmarks bar:

http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/

If you don't like that one you have a few more options:

http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

http://www.jamus.co.uk/demos/rwd-demonstrations/

http://codebomber.com/jquery/resizer/

http://www.benjaminkeen.com/open-source-projects/smaller-projects/responsive-design-bookmarklet/

Edit:

You might also create a link on your page that has href=

```
javascript:(function(d){if(d.getElementById('bm_resizer')){return}var%20scriptNode=d.createElement('script');scriptNode.src='http://branneman.github.com/resize-browser-window-bookmarklet/bookmarklet-resizer.js';d.body.appendChild(scriptNode)}(document));
```

Clicking on this link will open a popup from which you can choose a browser size.

[Source](http://bran.name/articles/resize-browser-window-bookmarklet/)

This is also available for all above websites which provide a bookmarklet. The difference between this one and the ones above is that this one doesn't use iframe.

Comment: Catalin, thanks for responding. But all of them load the page inside iFrame. I would like to provide preview buttons (mobile, tab, desktop) on the same actual page, I don't want to load the page inside iFrame.